# NullPointerException in java program for ldap connection

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Getting a NullPointer Exception when I Run the program. Please help !!

Code here:

```
import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.NamingEnumeration;
import javax.naming.directory.Attributes;
import javax.naming.directory.DirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchControls;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchResult;

public class LdapTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {

        final String PROVIDER_URL = "http://localhost:1389/dc=vysbank,dc=com";  //Enter LDAP URL here

        final Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,    "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, PROVIDER_URL);

        try {

            DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);

            String filter = "(uid=1234)"; // Enter User ID here.
            String[] attrIDs = {"uid","cn","mail"}; // Enter list of attributes to retrieve from LDAP here

            SearchControls ctls = new SearchControls();
            ctls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
            ctls.setReturningAttributes(attrIDs);

            NamingEnumeration answer = ctx.search("ou=People", filter, ctls);

            SearchResult searchResult = null;
            String cn=null;
            String uid=null;
            String mail=null;

            while (answer.hasMore()) {

                searchResult = (SearchResult) answer.next();
                Attributes attr = searchResult.getAttributes();
                cn=attr.get("cn").get(0).toString();
                uid=attr.get("uid").get(0).toString();
                mail=attr.get("mail").get(0).toString();

                System.out.println("Name: "+cn);
                System.out.println("User ID: "+uid);
                System.out.println("E-mail Address: "+mail);

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Please post the exactly error message.  What line is the NPE on?

Comment: Post the stack trace, where the null pointer is, sample input, expected output, and goal of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have `null` pointers here:

```
searchResult = (SearchResult) answer.next();
Attributes attr = searchResult.getAttributes();
cn=attr.get("cn").get(0).toString();
uid=attr.get("uid").get(0).toString();
mail=attr.get("mail").get(0).toString();
```

I would do `null` pointer checks to see if any values are null, and if so, give default empty string values:

```
if(attr != null){   
    if(attr.get("cn") != null && attr.get("cn").get(0) != null)
        cn=attr.get("cn").get(0).toString();
    else
        cn = "";
    if(attr.get("uid") != null && attr.get("cn").get(0) != null)
        uid=attr.get("uid").get(0).toString();
    else
        uid = "";
    if(attr.get("mail") != null && attr.get("cn").get(0) != null)
        mail=attr.get("mail").get(0).toString();
    else
        mail = "";
}
```

However, this all depends on the goal of the code.  If you are receiving values from a front end (say a web page), you should always to empty or `null` checks.  If you are creating variables and plan to use them, make sure those variables contain values by the time you use them.

Comment: i am also getting LdapTest.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details. What may be the reason for it ?

Comment: in the above code, how do i connect to the ldap using cn= Directory Manager? It won't allow me to get attributes of all the users in o=People

Comment: @user3150734 You might want to post another question because that seems to be another issue.  |=^/

Answer (score 1):

**[Null pointer Execption](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html)** is thrown when an application attempts to use null in a case where an object is required.

Below snippet throws NPE because you are calling a method on String a which is not properly initialized.

```
     String a = null;
     a.toString();
```

Debug your code to find such scenario.